# How do I take an element from a dropdown menu relate it to a stored variable and write that variable in another location on a web page?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

As it says in the question, I'm trying to take an element from a dropdown menu and relate it to a stored variable and then use an if statement to put the variable in another location on a web page. The example I have below has a dropdown with months and I want to post the number of days using `getElementByID`. What is a good way to make this work? Any help would be appreciated. Here is my html/JavaScript excluding CSS better or worse-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
   <script language="javascript">
        function displayDaysInTheMonth()
        {
            var  thirty = document.monthForm.30
            var thirtyone = document.monthForm.31
            var twentyeight = document.monthForm.28
            if (thirty == 'true' )
            {
                document.monthForm.getElementById('a').innerHTML = "has 30 days";
                return;
            }
            else if (thirtyone == 'true' )
            {
                document.monthForm.getElementById('b').innerHTML = "has 31 days";
                return;
            }
            else if (twentyeight == 'true' )
            {
                document.monthForm.getElementById('c').innerHTML = "has 28 days";
                return;
            }
            
        }
  </script>  
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
        <h2> David Platt's</h2>
        <h2>Monthly Day Count</h2>
        <form name='monthForm'>
            <select name='months' onchange='displayDaysInTheMonth();' style='float: left; margin: 0 10px 10px 15px;'>
                <option name = '31'>January</option>
                <option name = '28'>February</option>
                <option name = '31'>March</option>
                <option name = '30'>April</option>
                <option name = '31'>May</option>
                <option name = '30'>June</option>
                <option name = '31'>July</option>
                <option name = '31'>August</option>
                <option name = '30'>September</option>
                <option name = '31'>October</option>
                <option name = '30' >November</option>
                <option name = '31'>December </option>
            </select>
            <div name='result' class='result' id = 'a' id = 'b' id = 'c' >has # days.</div>
            <div class='clear'></div>
        </form>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jquery API](http://jquery.com/) to do this:

To Get dropdown value and set Div value to selected value do this

```
function displayDaysInTheMonth()
{
       var days = $('#months option:selected').val(); //gets dropdown value
       $("#a").html("has " + days + " days"); //sets div value here
}
```

Change your div to

```
<div name='result' class='result' id = 'a'>has # days.</div>
```

Change Drop down To

```
<select name='months' onchange='displayDaysInTheMonth();' 
  style='float: left; margin: 0 10px 10px 15px;'>
    <option value='31'>January</option>
    <option value='28'>February</option>
    <option value='31'>March</option>
    <option value='30'>April</option>
    <option value='31'>May</option>
    <option value='30'>June</option>
    <option value='31'>July</option>
    <option value='31'>August</option>
    <option value='30'>September</option>
    <option value='31'>October</option>
    <option value='30' >November</option>
    <option value='31'>December </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a way to do this using only javascript and it can be related to other number sets besides calendar dates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
   <script language="javascript">
        function displayDaysInTheMonth()
        {
        var numberOfDays = document.monthForm.months.value;
    var element = document.getElementById('a')
    element.innerHTML= "has " + numberOfDays + " days";
        }
  </script>  
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
        <h2> David Platt's</h2>
        <h2>Monthly Day Count</h2>
        <form name='monthForm'>
            <select name='months' onchange='displayDaysInTheMonth();' style='float: left; margin: 0 10px 10px 15px;'>
                <option value = '31'>January</option>
                <option value = '28'>February</option>
                <option value = '31'>March</option>
                <option value= '30'>April</option>
                <option value = '31'>May</option>
                <option value = '30'>June</option>
                <option value = '31'>July</option>
                <option value = '31'>August</option>
                <option value = '30'>September</option>
                <option value = '31'>October</option>
                <option value = '30' >November</option>
                <option value = '31'>December </option>
            </select>
            <div name='result' class='result' id = 'a' id = 'b' id = 'c' >has # days.</div>
            <div class='clear'></div>
        </form>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```